What is a conjugate unitary operator?
I'm studying operator theory and I have encountered the concept of a cojugate unitary operagtor several times. However, I cannot find any reliable references. There is one paper which claims that a conjuagete unitary operator on a Hilbert space is an operator $T$ satisfying $T^*=-T^{-1}$. But I suspect that it gives the wrong definition.
Could anyone help me with this concept?

Why do you suspect it is wrong

@EvangelopoulosFoivos According to some resources, a conjugate unitary operator $U$ would satisfy $U^*=U^{-1}$, just like a unitary operator. The difference is that a conjugate unitray operator isn't linear.

I’ve never seen this notion of conjugate unitary operators before. Assuming it meant anti-linear surjective isometric operators, then $U^\ast = U^{-1}$ is the correct one. $U^\ast = -U^{-1}$ is not possible as $U^\ast U$ is a positive linear operator for any linear or anti-linear $U$, but $-U^{-1} U = -I$ is not positive.

Personally, I use the terminology "anti-unitary operator", and without further context, I would guess that "conjugate unitary operator" means the same thing (just as "anti-linear" and "conjugate linear" are used as synonyms). So a conjugate unitary operator $U$ would be a surjective conjugate linear operator such that $\langle U\xi,U\eta\rangle=\langle \eta,\xi\rangle$. But it would be helpful to see a concrete example where this term is used to give a definitive answer.

@MaoWao Thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I need. The paper I'm reading says precisely that "conjuagte unitray" and "anti-unitary" mean the same thing.
